# About the distribution of balls in bins

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

Suppose we have $n$ balls and $n$ bins, and consider the following process: at stage $k$, we throw $\ln{n}$ balls into the bins, independently at random. We stop after $n/\ln{n}$ stages, when all balls have been thrown.

Let $N_k$ be the set of non-empty bins at the end of stage $k$. I guess that there exists some constant $b$ such that with high probability (that is, with probability that tends to 1 as $n$ grows to infinity; from now on, **whp**) $|N_k|\ge b\ln{n}$.

My question is as follows: suppose $N_k=\left\{n_k^1,n_k^2,...,n_k^{|N_k|}\right\}$ is ordered in an increasing order by the number of balls, such that if $i<j$, the number of balls in $n_k^j$ is at least the number of balls in $n_k^i$. For $0<c<1$, let $N_k^{(c)}=\left\{n_k^1,n_k^2,...,n_k^{c|N_k|}\right\}$; is it true that for every $0<c<1$ there exists $b=b(c)$ such that **whp** $\sum_{n\in N_k^{(c)}}|n|\ge bk\ln{n}$? If not, perhaps there exists $b=b(c,k)$ for which it would follow?

If there is such a constant, how fast would $\mathbb{P}\left(|N_k^{(c)}|<bk\ln{n}\right)$ go to $0$?

Comment: In the first sentence of paragraph 2, $N_k$ is a number.  In paragraph three, it seems to be a set.  When you write "in increasing order" in paragraph 3, I think you mean "in increasing order by number of balls".

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is very large compared to $k$, then $N_k$ will consist of $k\ln(n)$ bins each containing one ball (whp).  Thus, $|N_k^{(c)}|$ will be $ck\ln(n)$, and the sum will be $c \binom {k+1}2 \ln(n)$.  As $k$ increases, this outpaces $bk \ln(n)$, so $b(c)$ needs only to be chosen to accommodate small values of $k$.

I have not considered the further question (about how fast the probability goes to zero).

Comment: "... and the sum will be $c{k+1\choose 2}\ln{n}$ ..." - why?

Comment: Because we are summing $c \ln(n)$, $2c \ln(n)$, $\dots$, $kc\ln(n)$.

Comment: I apologize, I thought it was clear. The sum is not $\sum_{i=1}^k N_i^{(c)}$, but rather $\sum_{n\in N_k^{(c)}}|n|$.

Comment: What do you mean by $|n|$ for $n$ in $N_k^{(c)}$?

Comment: $N_k^{(c)}$ is a set of bins; thus, every $n\in N_k^{(c)}$ is a bin. The cardinality of that bin is $|n|$; by cardinality I mean the number of balls in that bin (at time $k$).

Comment: Okay, then I think what I wrote is correct, because whp there will only be one ball in each bin.